# How do I change the size of the scene in the .sks file?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to use the .sks file as a way of previewing what my app will look like. This is a Mac OSX app by the way.

I have changed the size of the window and SKScene programmatically in the AppDelegate.m file like this:

```
NSRect frame = [_window frame];
frame.size = CGSizeMake(1280, 740);
[_window setFrame: frame display: YES animate: NO];
[_window center]; //sets the window to the centre of the screen

GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
scene.size = CGSizeMake(1280, 720);
```

It doesn't seem like the .sks file reflects any of this. I just can't any info on how to use .sks files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that it's actually pretty easy. I don't know how I didn't notice this before. If you click on the .sks file and open the pane on the right side (it says "hide or show the utilities" when you mouse over it), then click on the scene inspector, you can change the width and height of the scene if the scene if your object of focus.

[image]